# Spring JMS manually creating MessageListenerContainer leakage when application stops

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic, spring-jms

I have a spring application that has to consume messages from some JMS queues. The number of queues has to be configurable, and because of this we have to manually create the consumers by reading a config file. So I can have x queues of type1 and y queues of type2, and all the connection details are specified in this config file.

I would say it is a rather complicated code, and I need to point out the following facts: I manually create the spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer and call start and stop on it, the transaction manager is distributed between the JMS and JDBC resources. Also, the application runs on WebLogic and the JMS queues are in WebLogic too.
The flow is that the app reads messages from the queues, tries to put the messages into the database, but if the database is down, the transaction (shared between both JMS and JDBC) is rolled back, so the messages is put back into the queue - this is the failover mechanism when database is down.

The issue that I am experiencing is that when I stop the application while it performs the failover mechanism, there are some JMS consumer threads that are not stopped. This way I get to leak threads and overload the system.

So my question is how can I make sure that when the application stops, it stops all the consumer threads? Calling stop on the message listener container doesn't seem to do the job.

Below are some code snippets:

config:

```
[
  {
    "factoryInitial": "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory",
    "providerUrl": "t3://localhost:7001",
    "securityPrincipal": "user",
    "securityCredentials": "password",
    "connectionFactory": "jms/QCF",
    "channels": {
      "type1": "jms/queue1"
    }
  }
]
```

java:

```
public class JmsConfig {

    private Map<String, List<DefaultMessageListenerContainer>> channels = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, MessageListener> messageConsumers;
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public JmsConfig(Map<String, MessageListener> messageConsumers, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        this.messageConsumers = messageConsumers;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
        List<JmsServerConfiguration> serverConfigurationList = readJsonFile();
        for (JmsServerConfiguration jmsServerConfiguration : serverConfigurationList) {
            Properties environment = createEnvironment(jmsServerConfiguration);
            JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
            jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(environment);
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = createConnectionFactory(jndiTemplate, jmsServerConfiguration);
            populateMessageListenerContainers(jmsServerConfiguration, jndiTemplate, connectionFactory);
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stopListenerContainers() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<DefaultMessageListenerContainer>> channel : channels.entrySet()) {
            for (DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer : channel.getValue()) {
                listenerContainer.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void populateMessageListenerContainers(
            JmsServerConfiguration jmsServerConfiguration,
            JndiTemplate jndiTemplate, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> channelsEntry = jmsServerConfiguration.getChannels().entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> channel : channelsEntry) {
            Destination destination = createDestination(jndiTemplate, channel.getValue());
            DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer =
                    createListenerContainer(connectionFactory, destination, messageConsumers.get(channel.getKey()));
            if (!channels.containsKey(channel.getKey())) {
                channels.put(channel.getKey(),
                        new ArrayList<DefaultMessageListenerContainer>());
            }
            channels.get(channel.getKey()).add(listenerContainer);
        }
    }

    private Properties createEnvironment(JmsServerConfiguration jmsServerConfiguration) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", jmsServerConfiguration.getFactoryInitial());
        properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", jmsServerConfiguration.getProviderUrl());
        properties.setProperty("java.naming.security.principal", jmsServerConfiguration.getSecurityPrincipal());
        properties.setProperty("java.naming.security.credentials", jmsServerConfiguration.getSecurityCredentials());
        return properties;
    }

    private ConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory(JndiTemplate jndiTemplate,
                                                      JmsServerConfiguration jmsServerConfiguration) throws Exception {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        connectionFactory.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
        connectionFactory.setJndiName(jmsServerConfiguration.getConnectionFactory());
        connectionFactory.setExpectedType(ConnectionFactory.class);
        connectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (ConnectionFactory) connectionFactory.getObject();
    }

    private Destination createDestination(JndiTemplate jndiTemplate, String jndiName) throws Exception {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean destinationFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        destinationFactory.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
        destinationFactory.setJndiName(jndiName);
        destinationFactory.setExpectedType(Destination.class);
        destinationFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (Destination) destinationFactory.getObject();
    }

    private DefaultMessageListenerContainer createListenerContainer(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Destination destination,
            MessageListener messageListener) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        listenerContainer.setDestination(destination);
        listenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        listenerContainer.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        listenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
        listenerContainer.afterPropertiesSet();
        listenerContainer.start();
        return listenerContainer;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to take a thread dump to see what the threads are doing. If they are doing something uninterruptible, you are out of luck.

Comment: the thread dump + running visualVM indeed helped to see what threads were causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was solved by calling listenerContainer.shutdown(); instead of stop().